# How do I ensure a Vimeo embedded video will play in all browsers?

Tags: html, vimeo, video-embedding

Vimeo videos are flash, is there a way to render the videos differently depending on the browser/device?

Here is the embed code Vimeo gives me:

```
<div class="video-holder">&nbsp;<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/#####"     
width="561" height="316" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen 
allowFullScreen></iframe></p>
```

What HTML/CSS would I need to use to ensure renderability in multiple browsers? Or is it better to convert from source?

Answer (score 2):

You are embedding inside an iframe. So if Vimeo supports the devices you target, it will display the appropriate content for those devices. Vimeo supports iOS and Android devices, possibly others as well. I think by default, if there is no support for Flash, it defaults to its H264 player, which means you are safe.

BTW, notice you have not closed your `div`.